# Hibernate sql select entity and column

Tags: sql, hibernate

My sql query looks something like

```
select e.*, EMP.pk_e.f_Data(e.id) as DATA from employee e
```

Data in `Employee` class is `transient`, how do I map this result list of this query to a list of `Employee`

Comment: That's not valid HQL. Show us the code of the relevant entities, and tell us what you want to do.

Comment: this query executes just fine, not sure what's invalid about it?

Comment: What is EMP? What if EMP.pk_e.f_Data(e.id) supposed to be? What is e.* supposed to mean?

Comment: EMP is the schema name which has a package pk_e in which the function f_Data() has been defined.
e.* was to select all columns from Employee table

Comment: You can't use schemas, packages and SQL functions in HQL queries. This query is not HQL. It's SQL. HQL uses entities, mapped fields/properties and associations. SQL uses tables and columns. They're different languages.

Comment: apologies....yes i'm using a SQLQuery